# How do I reach the top of the flagpole in 'Beware of the Rifts'

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

In World 5 of Super Mario Wonder, there's a stage "Beware of the Rifts" where I can't reach the top of the flagpole. The ground at the end of the stage is completely flat. I can see 3 red pipes in the ground, but I don't know if there's a way to raise them.

How do I reach the top of the flagpole in the stage 'Beware of the Rifts'?

[image: End of Beware of the Rifts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an invisible coin block in a small gap in the wall to the left of the red pipes. Hitting the block will make the pipes rise out of the ground, which you can jump from to reach the top of the flagpole.